# There's a way to bring all entities from bitrix24 in one method?

Tags: api, entities

i am a junior developer helping designing an app that uses bitrix24; i can see that the API has many methods to get all the available entities. I would like to know if someone knows an non official API that can bring them all with just one method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be advised, that this is not a homework production site. It is expected to tell what you have already tried, and in how far it didn't work, then ask a detailed question. Just dumping your questionnaire and asking others to fill it out for you is considered rude.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for an unofficial library, here's one

https://github.com/mesilov/bitrix24-php-sdk

Comment: thanks for your answer! i'm still an amateur in this